# failed to compile CUDA SDK on Lion

Tags: macos, cuda, osx-lion

I got the following errors:

```
/usr/include/libkern/i386/_OSByteOrder.h(60): error: identifier "__builtin_bswap32" is undefined

/usr/include/libkern/i386/_OSByteOrder.h(74): error: identifier "__builtin_bswap64" is undefined

../../common/inc/cutil_inline_runtime.h(176): error: class "cudaDeviceProp" has no member "tccDriver"

../../common/inc/cutil_inline_runtime.h(201): error: class "cudaDeviceProp" has no member "tccDriver"

../../common/inc/cutil_inline_runtime.h(307): error: identifier "CUFFT_UNALIGNED_DATA" is undefined
```

Any idea how to solve this problem? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem by making gcc point to gcc-4.2 instead of llvm-gcc